# Parsing html page that change content using PostBack function

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I'm using Python with Requests and BeautifulSoup to parse the pages, and everything worked well until on one of the pages buttons which have a PostBack function instead of a link appeared.

Buttons have this structure:

```
<a onclick="PostBack('FollowLink','2');return false;" href="#">Continue</a>
```

I have no idea on how to navigate to the next page since main link remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.  One is to manually inspect the Javascript and see what the PostBack function does, then simulate it.  The other is to change to something like Selenium, where you run an instance of Chrome which interprets the Javascript for you.  The first option would be less work.

Comment: Isnt there a way i can just call the function myself, given that i know the parameters?

Comment: Only if you have a Javascript interpreter in your program.  That's what Selenium provides.  As I said, since you know the parameters, it should be pretty easy to just evaluate the function yourself on paper and simulate the results.  It's probably just firing off a link.

Comment: Ok, i just had to use session,post() and provide same fields script uses to go to the next page. Thanks!